# How can I use the relax() method in pyscipopt?

Tags: python-3.x, scip

Here is some python code that illustrates the problem:

```
from pyscipopt import Model
master = Model("master LP")
relax  = master.relax()
```

This generates the error:

**builtins.AttributeError: 'pyscipopt.scip.Model' object has no attribute 'relax'**

These python statements are taken from [SCIP documentation](https://scipbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bpp.html) --- section **Column generation method for the cutting stock problem**.

Note, I am using Python 3.6.5 and pyscipopt 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

The `relax` method does not exist in PySCIPOpt.

What you link to is a book that, I think, was originally written for using Gurobi's python interface. The authors started translating it to use it with SCIP but this is not ready yet. Actually, you can even see it in the Todo at the beginning of the page you link to.
In any case, this is not the documentation of SCIP

Check the pyscipopt github page and if you have further problems/questions, please open an issue there

Comment: I looked a little deeper into the documentation on pyscipopt. And you are correct, the Todo in the scipbook shows: Adapt column generation to work with SCIP. IMHO one should not include an example that does not work in this book. I followed your advice &fserra and posted a comment on this at [GitHub](https://github.com/joaopedroso/scipbook/issues).